# Как вывести список всех категорий у товара

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Есть 3 таблицы:

```
public partial class Categories_table
{
    public string categorie_name { get; set; }
    public int categorie_id { get; set; }
}



public partial class AnimeList
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}



public partial class Anime_Categories
{
    public int anime_id { get; set; }
    public int categorie_id { get; set; }
}
```

Сам контекс данных:

```
public partial class Anime_BD : DbContext
{
    public Anime_BD()
        : base("name=AnimeTimesEntities")
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
    public virtual DbSet<Anime_Categories> Anime_Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AnimeList> AnimeLists { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Categories_table> Categories_table { get; set; }
}
```

Суть в том, что у 1 товара может быть несколько категорий.
Нужен запрос на поиск всех категорий у товара.

Comment: Использовать `myDatabaseContext.Categories` ?

Comment: @tym32167 Думаю, имеется ввиду список всех категорий конкретного продукта

Comment: @tym32167 пользователь тип нажимает на товар и переходит на страницу с ним,  и там выводиться к каким категориям он относится

Comment: Вас, в первую очередь,интересует сам запрос на получение списка товаров или что-то другое?

Comment: @IAMLERNCSHARP нет, у меня есть метод, который принимает число( id товара) и контроллер должен найти все его категории и передать в View и там они построчно выведутся. Мне нужен запрос на поиск всех категорий, к которым относится товар

Comment: `MyDataContext.Products.Where(product=>product.Id = id).SelectMany(product=>product.Categories);` ?

Comment: @tym32167 не понял SelectMany.  У продукта нет свойства Categories

Comment: Покажите ваши классы и контекст данных

Comment: @tym32167добавил в вопрос, а то в коменты нельзя добавить столько знаков

Comment: У вас `code first` или `database first`? У вас `Entity Framework` или `Entity Framework Core`?  Я не вижу у вас внешних ключей - связей между вашими моделями.

Comment: [Связь многие ко многим для EF](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.8.php), [Связь многие ко многим для EF Core](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.6.php)

Comment: database first. На диаграмме ключи показаны в Visual studio, в коде не знаю почему не проставлены

Comment: Не вижу никаких диаграмм. Покажите DDL ваших таблиц и расскажите, как именно вы генерируете контекст данных.

Comment: Мне сейчас лень думать, как это сделать одним запросом. В два будет вот так: `var animeCategoriesIds = db.Anime_Categories.Where(p => p.anime_id == yourAnimeId).Select(p => p.categorie_id)` и `var animeCategories = db.Categories_table.Where(p => animeCategoriesIds.Contains(p.categorie_id))`

Comment: Т.е. суть - выбрать из таблицы `Anime_Categories` все записи, которые содержат желаемый `anime_id`, и эти записи заджойнить с таблицей категорий по `categorie_id`

Comment: @AndreiKhotko а какой тип данных будет у `animeCategories` . Я же передаю типизированную модель во View

Comment: В данном случае он будет типа `Categories_table`. Все зависит от того, что вам нужно на View. Я бы на вашем месте создавал отдельные модели для View, а-ля `CategoryViewModel` и в ней определил бы все свойства, которые должны выводиться на View. И тогда `animeCategories` нужно конверитровать в `CategoryViewModel`

Comment: @AndreiKhotko идею понял, спасибо